# Notification Hub Bulk Import Failing with "Bad Format" error

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

I have followed the sample code provided by Microsoft at the following location:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/azure-services/dn790624(v=azure.100)

When I create the job NotificationHubJobType.ImportCreateRegistrations everything runs and completes without an error. However when I look at the output created by the job I have a failure file with every registration listed as follows:

```
<AppleRegistrationDescription xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2010/10/servicebus/connect"><RegistrationId i:nil="true" /><DeviceToken>1234</DeviceToken></AppleRegistrationDescription>,BadRequest,Bad Format
```

Notice at the end it says "BadRequest,Bad Format". I do not know what this if referring to or how to fix it. Here is a sample from my input file:

```
<AppleRegistrationDescription xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2010/10/servicebus/connect"><RegistrationId i:nil="true" /><DeviceToken>1234</DeviceToken></AppleRegistrationDescription>
<AppleRegistrationDescription xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2010/10/servicebus/connect"><RegistrationId i:nil="true" /><DeviceToken>4321</DeviceToken></AppleRegistrationDescription>
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We apologize for the inaccuracy in the document, we are in a process of fixing it. Can you please try to use NotificationHub SDK instead of Service Bus SDK mentioned in the document.

Also, the XML should look like:

< RegistrationDescription xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", Type=”AppleRegistrationDescription” xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2010/10/servicebus/connect">< RegistrationId i:nil="true" />< DeviceToken>1234< /DeviceToken>< /AppleRegistrationDescription>